# Zookeeper - upgrade from standalone to quorum

Tags: unix, solr, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

Currently I have a standalone ZK instances used in a test system.
But this test system has become production system and i would like to upgrade from 1 ZK instance to 3 without compromising availability of the SolrCloud system that ZK is overseeing.

From what i've read upgrading from 3 to 5 and so on is pretty easy using rolling restarts, but haven't found any info on going from standalone (1 instance) to 3.

Does anyone have any insight on this (anyone who might have tried it)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it after all by stopping node 1, updating configuration to know of all other servers and then creating the myid files for each node.
Then i restarted node 1 and started node 2,3,4 and everything went just fine.