# Zookeeper Standalone to Quorum without downtime

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I have a zookeeper which is running standalone for some reason and now we want it to run it as a quorum as it should be. Is there any way to make this upgrade without any downtime and without any data loss?

I have seen the question  [Zookeeper - upgrade from standalone to quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067560/zookeeper-upgrade-from-standalone-to-quorum), however, this one is quite old and the accepted solution has downtime. It simply shut down the zookeeper instance which does not fit my need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about setup a new separate zk cluster with the same data, and then switch the clients to the new cluster?

Comment: not possible until https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperReconfig.html#sc_reconfig_standaloneEnabled